# Shorter alternative for CHAR(9) (tab) in Excel formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, special-characters

I need to add several tabs in my formula so that when pasted as text the values have tabs. I use CHAR(9) for each tab, but using multiple CHAR(9)s made my formula very long, which would reach over the 8192 character limit. I could split the formula but try to avoid that because of the formula's complexity. Is there a shorter version of char(9) or other special characters? Also, is it possible to use regex keywords like \t inside the formulas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put the tab character in some cell, say **I1**, then instead of:

```
=A1 & CHAR(9) & B1
```

you can

```
=A1 & I1 & B1
```

since `I1` is only ***2*** characters rather than ***7***.

Comment: I never thought of doing that. Genius solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Better still, do as suggested, then give that cell (I1) a meaningful one-letter name, such as "T". Your formula can then become:

```
=A1 & T & B1
```